# Can someone give me a rough guideline for how long it will take to delete a Nearline storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

4 million JPG files, approximately 30TB in size.  I deleted it via their web interface, and it currently states "`Deleting 1 bucket`", and has done for an hour.

Just after someone's experience for a rough estimation as to how long this operation will take - another hour?  A day?  A week?!

Region: `europe-west1`, if that makes a difference.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you achieve the deletion? What are you looking for? What are  your pain points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [documentation on the deletion request timeline](https://cloud.google.com/security/deletion#deletion_timeline), on step 2 it says that:

> Once the deletion request is made, data is typically marked for deletion immediately and our goal is to perform this step within a maximum period of 24 hours.

A couple of points to be also considered are that:

- This timeline will vary depending on the number of files, so your case might take longer that that.
- If you files are organized in different folders, it would take longer to delete them since the system would have to enter each directory to delete.

One thing that you could do to speed up the deletion process is to use this command for parrallel deletion:

```
gsutil rm -m gs://bucket
```

**NOTE**: I don't think that the fact that your storage is a nearline storage has any effect on the timeline of deletion but I could not find any confirmation for that on the documentation.